# VBA search looping through ranges

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a situation where I have numbers in column A. I want to know if these numbers are found in column B. For example: A1 has the number 5554 and A2 has the number 163. B1 is 00051631 and B2 is 0000055549. 
The code should do the following: Search if one of the cells in column B contains 5554. Then move on to A2 and do the same.

Therefore both of these should return "true", as both numbers in column A exist in cells of column B.

```
Sub Search()

Dim StartCell As Integer
Dim EndCell As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'row counter
Dim x As Integer 'row counter2
Dim InvoiceNumber As Integer


StartCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
EndCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To EndCell
    InvoiceNumber = Cells(i, 1)
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 2), InvoiceNumber) > 0 Then
    Cells(i, 3).Value = InvoiceNumber
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

So basically what the above does is if A1 exists in B1, but it doesnt move on to check for B2 and so on...

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***<sub>Assuming:</sub>***

- both your columns are actually numbers formatted as text (as per the leading zeros)
- You need to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` as per your statement: `"....Therefore both of these should return "true"`

You could decide not to iterate over column B again and again. Instead you can perform a `Find` looking for values within values of column B:

***<sub>Sample Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Fill the array for a loop in memory
    lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & lr1)

    'Get the range to look in
    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & lr2)

    'Loop over the array and perform the search
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Set cl = rng.Find(arr(x, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(x, 3) = True 'If you want to insert boolean value
            '.Cells(x,3) = cl 'If you want to insert the found value
            '.Cells(x,3) = arr(x,1) 'If you want to insert the search value
        Else
            .Cells(x, 3) = False
        End If
    Next 

End With

End Sub
```

---

Another way would be to work through memory without `Find`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, x As Long
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Fill the first array for a loop in memory
    lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A1:A" & lr1)

    'Fill the second array for a filter
    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(.Range("B1:B" & lr2), 0, 1))

    'Loop over the array and perform the search
    For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)

        'Return an array of filtered values
        arr3 = Filter(arr2, arr1(x, 1))

        'Do something with the returned array
        If UBound(arr3) > -1 Then
            .Cells(x, 3) = True 'If you want to insert boolean value
            '.Cells(x,3) = arr3(1) 'If you want to insert the found value
            '.Cells(x, 3) = Join(arr3, ",") 'if you want to show all found values
            '.Cells(x,3) = arr(x,1) 'If you want to insert the search value
        Else
            .Cells(x, 3) = False
        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

In both cases you might want to make sure you also format column C as text.

Comment: Hi, Thanks this is working great! The situation is simplified from the actual goal. I am assuming I can modify this so that basically A and B are just on different sheets and possibly making several "true" checks. Can you clarify that is the lr1 + arr basically defining the size of column A and lr2 + arr defining the column B?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the `+`, but lr1 indeed does find the last used row of column A, which lr2 does for column B

Comment: Could you help me with modifying the code. What if the column A and B of the example are on different sheets?

Comment: @Carlsberg789, do you see where I open a `With Sheets1` statement? All references after that untill the `End With` with a dot in front will refer to that parent worksheet. If you want to referer to another sheet you can open another with statement or directly refer to that worksheet: `Worksheets("Sheets2").Range(` etc...

Comment: Oh great thanks! Got it to work on separate sheets now. Looks ugly but does the job. 

> Is there a way to return the value of a cell next to the cell, where the value was found? For Example A1 has value 42 which was found in cell B45. I would like to return the value from C45.

Comment: `cl.Offset(0,1)` will do just fine @Carlsberg789 =). Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't loop over B column at all, that's why you are having problem.

It is better to store row number in variable and loop between those variables:

```
Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long
For aRow = startRow To endRow
  invoiceNumber = Cells(aRow, 1).Value
  For bRow = startRow To endRow
    If InStr(1, Cells(bRow, 2).Value, invoiceNumber) > 0 Then
      Cells(aRow, 3).Value = invoiceNumber
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version

```
Sub Search()

Dim StartCell As Integer
Dim CellSource As Range
Dim CellSearch As Range
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim testValue As String


Dim i As Integer 'row counter
Dim x As Integer 'row counter2
Dim InvoiceNumber As Integer


StartCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") ' a you sure you need this?
SourceRange = Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
SearchRange = Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))


For Each CellSource In SourceRange
    For Each CellSearch In SearchRange
        testValue = "*" & CellSource & "*"
        If CellSearch Like testValue Then
            CellSource.Offset(0, 2).Value = CellSource
        End If
    Next
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using VBA, but you know this could be done in a couple of ways using just an Excel formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH("*" &A1&"*",B:B,0))
```

Comment: Nice, according to OP's code, OP wants the Item in Column A to appear next to column B. Can you change it so column A is in column C

Comment: this will put it in the column where the formula is, so the formula just goes in column C

Comment: Yes i do in fact need it in VBA. But actually this will be _extremely_ useful to me as well. Can you clarify the "*" -parts of the formula. Basic match the situation is: (Value_to_search,Range_to_search_from,0). Is this basically: (Anything+Value_to_Search+Anything, Range_to_search_from,0))? What is the purpose of the space between the first "*" and &A1&?

Comment: Actually i tried this, doesnt really work :) Is it possible to do an index match in a way that i have invoice 55534 and i want to match it with 115553400. Basically i have random numbers before and after, but the value is in the cell. So an isnumber + search would do the trick but this formula seemed easier

Comment: Aaand im continuing, works with text, not with numbers. Interesting.

Comment: "*" &A1&"*" this tells it to wildcard match before and after the contents of AI in column B